# Are an electronic circuit/schematics patentable there are lawsuits or literature about?

Tags: patentability, law, lawsuit, communications-electrical, electronics

My name is Diego Camilo Peña Ramírez, i'm employee in the patent office in Colombia and we are looking for information about patentability in electronic circuits, more specifically about the distribution of the components inside the circuit.

I wonder if There are literature, lawsuits, examples, laws or something about the topic, we are still building the regulation and we are taking USA law as reference.

Thank you

Comment: I'm afraid I don't fully follow your question. Are you asking whether electronic circuits are patentable?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer and sorry for my english:

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer and sorry for my english: We are looking for how the US law manages the electronic circuits, and how you manage that topic, we are here in the patent office Colombia trying to make a regulation or procedure for try to manage the applications related to electronic circuits ...

Comment: Electronic circuits are clearly patentable. That said, I think it would be best to try to contact the USPTO directly. As a representative of your countries government I would hope they would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is helpful. Ask Patents is not part of the USPTO but is just a group of volunteers trying to provide patent information to the general public. Our answers are not authoritative. The USPTO does have a department of people specifically to work with the offices of other countries. It is called the Office of International Patent Cooperation. A link to their [organization chart](https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/OIPC%20Org%20Chart%20April%206%202018.pdf) with the names of people responsible for various topic.

Comment: That said, Ask Patents is an extremely valuable resource for getting solid advice from experienced inventors!